# Excel 2013 IF/AND statement using more than one workbook in a spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to set up a sort of schedule in Excel 2013.

What I want to do is have an individual workbook inside the spreadsheet for each of the 7 people I am trying to make this for, on these workbooks there are columns for each weekday and 24 rows(no for an hour block of each day.

I have the cells formatted to be answered Yes or No if they will be available during that hour block and I want to have the main workbook in the spreadsheet show me a yes or no for hour blocks each day when everyone chose yes.

This is the basic formula I am using with the titles of the workbooks changed so no ones name is posted here.

```
=If(And(WB1!B2="Yes", WB2!B2="Yes", WB3!B2="Yes", WB4!B2="Yes", WB5!B2="Yes", WB6!B2="Yes"), Yes, No)
```

This basic concept works with just the If statement checking to see if one of the workbooks has as Yes answer, but once I add in the AND the whole formula falls apart on me and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong or if this is even possible to accomplish with Excel.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented your sample in my German Excel and found that

```
=WENN(UND(Tabelle1!A1="yes";Tabelle2!A1="yes");"yes";"no")
```

works just like you want. Maybe all you're missing is the quotes around the result values?